# Data Transformation in PySpark after DataFrame.GroupBy

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Data Frame that I am grouping by column "identifier1". What I need to do is apply a transform to two columns in order to create a summary out of them and I am failing to understand some very basic part of PySpark/PySpark-SQL

I have tried various forms of F.sum and F.expr and I am not getting the data from the Grouped Data Frame and I am getting the string in the equation instead of the data

```
groupedDF = df.groupBy('Indentifier1')
resultDF = groupedDF.agg(
    F.sum('col1' * 'col2' / F.sum('col2'))
)
```

I'm really just trying to get a weighted sum for the summary out of the two columns. `'Col1'` * the weight of `'Col2'` `('Col2' / sum('Col2'))`

I really feel like I am missing something basic.

Comment: were you getting this error. "It is not allowed to use an aggregate function in the argument of another aggregate function" can you post the error and also your dataframe and expected output

Comment: you will most likely need to do this in 2 or more steps since you have sub query aggregation over a group by ... if you post your desired output we can code it up